# can you solve these?

Tags: pattern, sequence

Here are some sequence patterns. I have no clue.

[image: Pattern 1]

[image: Pattern 2]

[image: Pattern 3]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. Are these from an ongoing contest?

Comment: Seriously? Bart Simpson, Milhouse and even Ralph Wiggum got a variant on Pattern 2. (In your defense, Lisa was stumped by it.)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your question so that the images are actually visible and not just external links, please?

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold until proper attribution of its original source is provided. It looks like you're asking us to solve a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content that you did not create yourself, please **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)** - at minimum you need to let us know where this came from, and any additional context you can provide is usually a big help to solvers. Posts which use someone else's content without disclosing where it came from are generally deleted.

Answer (score 2):

#### Pattern 1

> This is two independent patterns overlaid. 
> I show them both below, in arbitrary (top-to-bottom) order,
> with the fourth image included.
>
> The patterns correspond to the (outer) square being a clock face
> with two hands. 
> The first pattern has a hand
> with a hollow (white with a black border) square on its clockwise side. 
> This moves 45° counterclockwise at each step:
>  [image]
>
> The second has a hand
> with a solid black square on its counterclockwise side. 
> This moves 90° clockwise at each step:
>  [image]
> (Note that, in the third image,
> the solid black square overlays and obliterates the hollow square.)
>
> Overlay the fourth images from the two series and you get Answer A:
>  [image]

#### Pattern 2:

> This is just the (capital) letters “C”, “D” and “E”
> overlaid / overlapped with their mirror images:
>             [image]
>
> So the fourth image is the (capital) letter “F”
> overlaid / overlapped with its mirror image:
>             [image]
>
> which is Answer A.

#### Pattern 3:

If we number the images left-to right, top-to-bottom
(so the top row is images 1, 2 and 3), then

> - Image 1 is image 3 plus image 7.
>
>   Image 6 is image 2 plus image 4.
>
>   This leaves images 5, 8 and 9 unaccounted for. 
>   Well, Image 5 is image 8 plus image A.
>
> So, again, the answer is A.

Comment: Quick reminder: If you can, with reasonable certainty, tell that the OP is not posting their own content, it's better to point out the attribution/no-plagiarism requirement than to spend time answering a question likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution

> to all of the patterns is A

Pattern 1:

> - the solid black square moves 90 degrees clockwise
>  - the not-filled square moves 90 degrees counter-clockwise and rotates 45 degrees
>  - of the two straight lines from the edge to the center, one moves 90 degrees clockwise and the other moves 45 degrees counter-clockwise

Pattern 2:

> Each image is composed of the letter C, D, E and its mirrored version.

Pattern 3:

> Number the images as follows:
>  1 2 3
>  4 5 6
>  7 8 9
>  Then, 3 and 7 together form 1; 4 and 2 together form 6; and A and 8 together form 5.

Comment: Quick reminder: If you can, with reasonable certainty, tell that the OP is not posting their own content, it's better to point out the attribution/no-plagiarism requirement than to spend time answering a question likely to be closed.